# Nexus 5 not being detected on pc

Tags: android, nexus-5

Till yesterday my nexus 5 was connecting,
Now when last it was connected to my brother's computer here's what i did:
I was trying to take a 20 gb file from his comp so didn't have enough space, so what i did was figure all i need is photos backed em at his comp and pressed ctrl + a on my internal memory and deleted everything i mean everything in my phone memory to make space, now took the file came back home to my pc and Zoink my nexus phone is not being detected, i mean i went device manager and there's a mtp sign sitting with exclamation mark, now before you say anything here me out.
To keep it short and sweet have read a lot of posts done a lot of things and none worked, did mtp ptp switch, device manager uninstall and reconnect, turn on usb debug then install drivers downloaded from google, turn off usb debugging, Belive me i done most of it but none of em is working, m betting this has something to  do with my ctrl + a delete on my internal memory and if so wht's the solution.

Comment: You might get better feedback @ http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is how I solded it:

- On the Device Manager, right-click the device entry, and click Uninstall
- On the Confirm Device Removal dialog box, click the **Delete the driver software for this device** option to delete the driver package that was used for the device.
- Unplug/replug your device

This did the work for me. Hope that helps you.